# Loading PDF file in iframe from another domain (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, iframe, header

I want to display a PDF file from another domain on my website. The website containing PDF file is developed in the Laravel 6 framework. Laravel response is as follow:

```
return response()
   ->file(storage_path($this->sharedFilesPath . $file->path),
     ['X-Frame-Options' => 'allow-from https://www.example.com/']);
```

But after using the URL in the iframe, `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` appears and the browser doesn't show the PDF, and if I type the URL in the browser's new page then the PDF file is loading.

Browser Console:

```
Refused to display '<URL>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Update:

Added the following header as well but no success:

```
'Content-Security-Policy' => 'frame-src https://www.example.com'
```

Comment: [allow-from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) seems to be deprecated and not work anymore. The MDN site suggests using [`Content-Security-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)`: frame-src https://www.example.com`

Comment: Added the `Content-Security-Policy` but still get `Refused to display '<URL>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.` error

Comment: Is anything else setting the `X-Frame-Options` header? Like a server config or middleware?

Comment: I don't know about the Laravel default behavior, but I didn't set the header anywhere else by my self

Comment: The `allow-from` value no longer works. Look at these [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options). Only availbable values are `deny` and `sameorigin`

Comment: But in the browser console, the response header contains `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin`